# Yahoo: Downloading Stock data from symbols with a period (.)

Tags: programming, data, market-data, market

Hi: I'm using R to start learning about quantitative finance. I'm good at R, just learning finance. 
Some stocks on the TSX have periods in their names, usually indicating that it's a class B share, for example. The usual functions to download stock data seem to crash on these characters. Thoughts?

```
#load library
library(fImport)
library(quantmod)
#these work
yahooSeries(symbols='AQN')
getSymbols('AQN', src='yahoo')
#These don't
yahooSeries(symbols='ATD.B')
getSymbols('ATD.B', src='yahoo')
```

Comment: Aren't you looking for ATD-B.TO?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your symbol ATD.B is returning not found. In Yahoo a dot usually precedes the Exchange (eg. AQN.TO refers to Algonquin, Toronto Exchange). A minus sign (or dash) precedes the class: e.g. RDS-B refers to Royal Dutch, class B. So Try using ATD-B or ATD-B.TO instead of ATD.B.

Comment: HI: OK, that works for most except there are a few securities that are still causing problems.

Comment: For example, securities that are labelled "-UN.TO" are choking on this. But when I go to the Yahoo Finance website, they do just fine. Examples: BBU-UN.TO and NVU-UN.TO.  It seems like these are both real estate trusts. Thoughts?

Comment: Interestingly enough I was unable to download a history .csv file for BBU-UN even through manual web site lookup (although I was able to get yesterday's quote). Maybe a problem with Yahoo? Or they just don't have history for these stocks?